# How do you address something that is between heavily damaged and lightly damaged?

Tags: grammar

Title says it all. If something is just mediumly damaged, how do you address it? I know that mediumly damaged is not a correct English. We can go with heavily damaged, lightly damaged, but what about something that is neither heavily nor lightly damaged? How do you address something that is in-between?

Comment: *Moderately* damaged is common.

Comment: *Severely damaged* sounds better than *heavily damaged*.

Comment: Or a "moderate amount of damage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say **"moderately damaged"** as a part of a general damage classification, which includes:

- Light damage
- Moderate damage
- Severe damage